# Vagrant rsync not such a file or directory

Tags: vagrant, rsync

I am using vagrant 1.7.2 on windows 7 and try to rsync files to Ubuntu box. 
When I am trying to do vagrant up I am getting an error on syncing folders. Do I need a diffrent version of rsync or  vagrnat?

Vagrant 1.7.2

rsync 3.1.1

Host Windows 7

Guest Ubantu 14.04

### Vagrant file

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www",
              rsync__auto: true,
              type: :rsync
```

### LOG

```
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /c/Development/websites/fams/ => /var/www
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /c/Development/websites/fams/
Guest path: /var/www
Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/krzysztofl/.vagrant.d/boxes/cdl_vis-VAGRANTSLASH-fams/0.1.2/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key' --exclude .vagrant/ /c/Development/websites/fams/ vagrant@127.0.0.1:/var/www
Error: cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Users/krzysztofl/.vagrant.d/boxes/cdl_vis-VAGRANTSLASH-fams/0.1.2/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Users/krzysztofl/.vagrant.d/boxes/cdl_vis-VAGRANTSLASH-fams/0.1.2/virtualbox/vagrant_private_key
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rsync: change_dir "/c/Development/websites/fams" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add the following in your Vagrantfile

```
ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"] = ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"].to_s + " cygwin"
```

this is explained in the [github issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3230#issuecomment-62588180)

Comment: I tried this fix and its not working for me. I am not using cygwin console, I am using ConEmu if that make any different?